# Observing a list of Swift KeyPaths

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I have the following code which adds an observer on two properties:

```
    obs = []

    let xa = self.observe(\CirclePolygon.radius, options: [.new]) { (op, ch) in
        callback()
    }
    obs.append(xa)


    let xb = self.observe(\CirclePolygon.origin.x, options: [.new]) { (op, ch) in
        callback()
    }
    obs.append(xb)
```

It works, but I don't like the duplciation. I have tried to pass a list of KeyPaths:

```
    obs = []

    let keyPaths = [\CirclePolygon.radius, \CirclePolygon.origin.x]
    for keyPath in keyPaths {
        let xa = self.observe(keyPath, options: [.new]) { (op, ch) in
            callback()
        }
        obs.append(xa)
    }
```

But I get the compiler error: `Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred`

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What are the specific types of your `CirclePolygon.radius` and `CirclePolygon.origin.x` properties? I guess they are different types (e.g. `Double` and `CGFloat`).

Comment: @robmayoff Correct, they are of different types, I'd also like to expand whatever the solution is to handle KeyPaths of type: String, CGFloat, NSNumber etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, remember that KVO only works on instances of `NSObject` (or a subclass). So if the `origin` property of `CirclePolygon` is a `CGPoint` or some other `struct`, you'll get a run-time error when you try to register an observer of `\CirclePolygon.origin.x`, because KVO cannot apply to the `x` property of a `CGPoint`.

Second, the key paths you gave have different types. Let's say (to address my first point) you want to observe `radius` (a `Double`) and `origin` (a `CGPoint`). The key paths have different types:

```
\CirclePolygon.radius   // type: KeyPath<CirclePolygon, Double>
\CirclePolygon.origin   // type: KeyPath<CirclePolygon, CGPoint>
```

If you try to put these in a single array, without explicitly specifying the type of the array, Swift will deduce it as follows:

```
let keyPaths = [\CirclePolygon.origin, \CirclePolygon.radius]
// deduced type of keyPaths: [PartialKeyPath<CirclePolygon>]
```

It deduces `[PartialKeyPath<CirclePolygon>]` because `PartialKeyPath<CirclePolygon>` is the nearest common ancestor of both `KeyPath<CirclePolygon, Double>` and `KeyPath<CirclePolygon, CGPoint>`.

So, in the `for` loop where you iterate over the array, you're passing an object with static type `PartialKeyPath<CirclePolygon>` as the `keyPath` argument of the `observe(_:options:changeHandler:)` method. Unfortunately, that method is [declared as follows](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3f4796a4ecd21e2582d7213a1feadf2fc40e83a7/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/NSObject.swift):

> ```
> public func observe<Value>(
>         _ keyPath: KeyPath<Self, Value>,
>         options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [],
>         changeHandler: @escaping (Self, NSKeyValueObservedChange<Value>) -> Void)
>     -> NSKeyValueObservation
> ```

Which is to say, the method requires a `KeyPath<Self, Value>` but you're passing a `PartialKeyPath<Self>`, so Swift emits an error. As is often the case with Swift errors around generic type problems, the error isn't very helpful.

You cannot solve this problem by casting, because you cannot (for example) cast `KeyPath<CirclePolygon, Double>` to `KeyPath<CirclePolygon, Any>`.

One solution may be to use a local function to encapsulate the common code, like this:

```
func register(callback: @escaping () -> ()) -> [NSKeyValueObservation] {
    func r<Value>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<CirclePolygon, Value>) -> NSKeyValueObservation {
        return observe(keyPath, options: []) { (_, _) in
            callback()
        }
    }

    return [
        r(\.radius),
        r(\.origin),
    ]
}
```